# Should Frontend or Backend handles currency conversions?

Tags: architecture, frontend, backend, currency

I have a marketplace where people can sell their products in the currency of their home country.
And people from all over the world can buy their products, but they are always charged in the currency of the product's seller.

So if a seller in Germany sells something to someone in the UK, the UK buyer will pay it in Euros.

But I want users to be able to *see* prices in their local currency, and they can choose their local currency via some interface.

So my question is: who should own the currency conversion?

Should the Backend only store the "original" price in the "original" currency (the one defined by the seller), and the Frontend handles the currency conversion based on user's preference?
Or should the Backend handles the conversion and provide the price in any currency back to the Frontend?

From the scalability perspective, we are currently only working with a couple of different currencies, but we plan to expand to several new ones (maybe a couple of dozen).

And our products involve a website, iOS and Android native apps, and they should all work in the same way.

Comment: How accurate is your region (which currency to use) detection - or will you let users choose which currency they want prices displayed as?

Comment: Users will choose, but the default currency will be fetched by geolocation.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion this should be done at backend side.

1. Every new currency doesn't need new version of Android/iOS app, so this will be done quickly.
2. Can currency conversion and validation on frontend side be "hacked" in some way? This is only client-side script, so backend validation is a must. And if validation is a must, conversion on backend side comes in natural way, right?
3. You have to have some API which tells you in what price is current Eur / USD / etc. "Static" values like "1.20 is a Eur to Usd rate" saved on frontend can do some trouble with unstable currencies. So maybe there are some third-part APIs with currencies prices, but on frontend you need ask for currency price every time. On backend this will be in one place and cached probably. API calls from backend to currencies API will be done 1/2 times per day, API calls from frontend can kill your pricing plans at currency API, so this cant be optimised properly.

Comment: Good one for calling out client-side security considerations.  Use of a 3rd party currency API is a great idea too.